# How can I print more than one variable in my print function(Python)?

Tags: python

I'm brand new to python and my teacher showed me an example on how to write multiple variables in a print function but I am getting a syntax error. Did I write it wrong? How can I fix this?

```
def fahrenheit_to_celcius(num):
    celciusTemp=(num-32)*0.556
    print("When you convert %s to celcius the result is %s",%(num, 
celciusTemp))
```

Above is just a simple function I'm writing as part of some beginner exercise. But when I run the code it says my print function has invalid syntax.

Comment: print("when you convert {} to celcius the result is {:f}".format(num,celciusTemp))

Answer (score 2):

Use this code.

```
def fahrenheit_to_celcius(num):
    celciusTemp=(num-32)*0.556
    print("When you convert %s to celcius the result is %s" % (num, 
celciusTemp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you seem to be working in Python 3, there is a really cool way to format strings that I absolutely love. With this method, your `print()` would look like

```
print(F"When you convert {num} to Celsius, the result is
{celsiusTemp}.")
```

With this method, you can write pretty much any python in between `{}` and python automatically puts the returned output of that code in your string.

Answer (score 1):

Here I fixed your code. I also added a few lines of extra code so that it is a bit more readable for your prof. It should be easy enough for you to understand. Here's the code:

```
def fahrenheit_to_celcius(num):
    celciusTemp=(num-32)*0.556
    print("When you convert {} fahrenheit to celcius the result is {:f}".format(num,celciusTemp))
num = int(input("Input the degrees of fahrenheit you want to convert to celcius:"))
fahrenheit_to_celcius(num)
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Format. In your case. :f (Displays fixed point number (Default: 6))

```
string = "when you convert {} to celcius the result is {:f}".format(num,celciusTemp)
print(string)
```

More information please check this link https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format

Answer (score -1):

Remove the comma before the percent sign.